# MVC Bind the drop down follow another drop down using JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller

I have two ListBoxs (multiple selection dropdownlist type) like follwing:

```
 @Html.ListBox("counTryIds", new SelectList(Model.CountryModels, "CountryId", "CountryName"), new { @class = "chosen-select", @id = "lbCountry", data_placeholder = "Select country...", style = "width: 100%" })
 @Html.ListBox("provinceIds", new SelectList(Model.ProvinceModels, "ProvinceId", "ProvinceName"), new { @class = "chosen-select", @id = "lbProvince", data_placeholder = "Select province...", style = "width: 100%" })
```

I would like to get list Province following some selected countries.

Example:

> If I have 2 countries: VietNam, USA and 3 provinces: HaNoi, NewYork, HoChiMinh.
>
> > If I select VietNam => Dropdownlist Province will have HaNoi and HoChiMinh for selecting. As the same if I select USA -> have only NewYork. Beyond if select all countries VietNam, USA => show all provinces
> >     In controller I got 2 lists:

```
 reportLand.CountryModels = countries.ToList();
 reportLand.ProvinceModels = provinces.ToList();
```

The Country models:

```
 public string CountryId{ get; set; }

 [Required(ErrorMessage = CommonConstants.ErrorRequired)]
 public string CountryName { get; set; }
```

And Province model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = CommonConstants.ErrorRequired)]
public string ProvinceId { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = CommonConstants.ErrorRequired)]
public string ProvinceName{ get; set; }

public string CountryId { get; set; }
public string CountryName { get; set; }
```

As mentioned, I would like to get list Province following some selected countries. But I don't want to recall controller again to connect DB, only process in front end via jQuery or Js

Can everyone help me ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: nobody can help me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Jquery or ajax for get your solution.Just visit the following links it il help you

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/working-with-dropdownlist-in-mvc-5/

[Fill drop down list on selection of another drop down list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17013644/fill-drop-down-list-on-selection-of-another-drop-down-list)