# Bind a dropdownlist in gridview with different table each row

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am creating student portal where I have a form in which students will fill their academic details.

For this purpose I am using GridView.
Different course details are row wise arranged.
First row is for 12th (Higher Secondary)
Next row is for UG course
Next row is for PG course
And so on for higher courses.

I want to bind a Dropdownlist in first cell in each row with different tables. Example: For row of UG, table will be UG_Course_Master, For row of PG, table will be PG_Course_Master an so on.

Please help me with it.

[image: My Gridview view]

Comment: Please check the link below link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17013644/fill-drop-down-list-on-selection-of-another-drop-down-list

Comment: thank u so much, but ye link mere liye helpful nahi h.