# Ajax call to populate select list when another select list changes

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Following on from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16897146/bind-drop-down-list-using-jquery-ajax-on-change-of-first-ddl), I'm attempting to populate a select list of 'cities' when another select list of 'countries' changes.  I followed the same approach as the linked post and as outlined below implementing Darin's suggestion for the success().  It works great 'most' of the time (which is really odd).  What I mean is, out of all my 'countries', 90% of the change events return the select list item(s) object(s), the other 10% return a single string value.  Why would it vary?  It should either work or not...

View

```
<!--Country-->
                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                        <label class="control-label ">City </label>
                        <br />
                       <select id="Country" name="Country" class="form-control">
                           <option value="">List of countries from Model...</option>
                       </select>
                    </div>


<!--City-->
                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                        <label class="control-label ">City </label>
                        <br />
                       <select id="City" name="City" class="form-control">
                           <option value="">Select a country first...</option>
                       </select>
                    </div>


<!--Inside my script -->
<script>
 $('#Country').change(function () {
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("CityDropDownList", "Home")',
            type: "GET",
            data: { country: selectedValue },
            success: function (result) {

                var cityDropDownList = $('#City');
                cityDropDownList.empty();
                $.each(result, function () {
                    cityDropDownList.append(
                        $('<option/>', {
                            value: this.Value,
                            text: this.Text
                        })
                    );
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Controller

```
 public JsonResult CityDropDownList(string country)
    {
        var results = (from c in db.PageStats
                       where c.Country.Equals(country)
                       orderby c.City
                       select c.City).ToList().Distinct();

            //db.PageStats.Where(x => x.Country.Equals(country)).OrderBy(x => x.City).Select(x => x.City).Distinct().ToList();

        List<SelectListItem> cities = new List<SelectListItem>();

        foreach(var item in results)
        {
            SelectListItem city = new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = item,
                Value = item
            };
            cities.Add(city);
        }             
        return Json(cityList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: what string value is it returning ? Are you saying instead of an array it returns a single string ?

Comment: For the 90% success cases, it returns either 1 or many [object Object].  For the 10%, it lists every city in a giant string.  I added alert(result);  just after success(){ to debug.

Comment: That sounds strange ! Your code looks fine. I recommend putting your change event registration inside document.ready event.

Comment: Not related, but there is no point creating and returning `List<SelectListItem>` (the client has no knowledge of what a `SelectListItem` is). Since results is `IEnumerable<string>`, then just return `return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` and use `value: this, text: this`

Comment: Shyju - yes it gets injected into document.ready in the shared layout.   Stephen - good point, thanks.  @AllElse - what could be causing my issue?

Answer (score 4):

SOLVED

```
$('#Country').change(function () {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    $.get({
        url: '@Url.Action("CityDropDownList", "Home")',
        data: { country: selectedValue },

        success: function (result) {

            alert(result);
            var cities = $('#City');
            cities.empty();

            $.each(result, function () {

                cities.append(
                        $('<option>', {
                            value: this.Value
                        }).text(this.Text)
                    );
            });
        }
    });
});
```