# Change selected value dropdown C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core-2.0

Afternoon,

I have two dropdown lists, ServiceName and GroupName. Basically when the value of ServiceName changes I would like the content of GroupName to update based on the selected value, which both share the ServiceId field in my database.

However, I can't dynamically change the selected value, I have hardcoded in 1 and tried to use Jquery to change to no avail.

```
public IActionResult Create(string id)
{
    ViewData["id"] = id;

    var list = new SelectList(_context.DatabaseService.Where(t => t.id == id).Select(i => i.Service), "ServiceId", "ServiceName", 1);
    var selected = list.SelectedValue.ToString();

    ViewData["GroupName"] = new SelectList(_context.ComponentGroups.Where(t => t.ServiceId == Int32.Parse(selected)), "GroupId", "GroupName");
    ViewData["ServiceName"] = list; 

    return View();
}
```

Is it possible to get my selected variable to equal the active item in my ServiceName dropdown?

Comment: Yes, its possible but your method should be return JsonResult

Comment: @Md.AbdulAlim - JsonResult implements IActionResult through inheritance.

Comment: I'd stick with the jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue by using a combination of this solution [Ajax call to populate select list when another select list changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36393409/ajax-call-to-populate-select-list-when-another-select-list-changes) and this solution [bind drop down list using jquery ajax on change of first ddl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16897146/bind-drop-down-list-using-jquery-ajax-on-change-of-first-ddl).

I created a new method which shows all my groups in JSON format

```
    public IActionResult GetGroupByService()
    {
        var grouping = _context.ComponentGroups;
        return Json(grouping);
    }
```

Then in my View I used JQuery to populate an empty select list from the data return from the JSON array

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function GetGroup(_serviceId) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetGroupByService", "Components")',
        data: { serviceId: _serviceId },
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            var markup = "";
            for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                if (data[x].serviceId == _serviceId) {
                    markup += "<option value=" + data[x].groupId + ">" + data[x].groupName + "</option>";
                }
            }
            $("#GroupId").html(markup).show();
        },
        error: function (reponse) {
            alert("error : " + reponse);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Here are my select lists

```
<label asp-for="ServiceId" class="control-label">Service Name</label>
<select asp-for="ServiceId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ServiceName" onchange="javascript:GetGroup(this.value);">

<label asp-for="GroupId" class="control-label">Group Name</label>
<select asp-for="GroupId" name="GroupId" class="form-control"></select>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution